# How to remove/reset/not inherit the CSS properties of a DIV/element/... within the same CSS document?

Tags: css, properties, element, reset

I have a certain line in my CSS file, which declares some properties needed to design the navigation on a normal desktop computer.

For desktop:

```
#nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul:hover > a {color: #bbb; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .95);}
```

By using media queries I want to redesign the navigation, when the website is being looked at in a mobile device. So far, so good.

My problem is now, that the media queries which follow-up later in the CSS document inherit those values above, when in fact I just need them gone. I need to have NO hover effect in that navigation drop-down (because iOS Safari does not like hover).

So, I tried just an empty input like:

For mobile:

```
#nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul:hover > a {}
```

But that did not work. It still shows the behaviour of the above-mentioned #nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul:hover > a.

To cut a long story short, how do I get #nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul:hover > a {} empty, rid of it or not to inherit the values from above in the CSS file?

Btw, I can not change code on the navigation, because it is generated by Wordpress. Thank you very much in advance, guys.

Comment: Why don't you use `@media` queries to target desktop screens as well? I think you've run into a X/Y problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove a rule, you could just override it with a more specific selector.

Another option if you are using media queries is to include desktop rule in a media query and get enabled only to the specified dimension like:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul :hover > a {
     color: #bbb;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .95);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Load different stylesheets

   `<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 779x)' href='mobile.css' />`
   `<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 780px)' href='desktop.css' />`
2. as commented by @Hashem / @emmanuel answer
3. override in your media queries

   `#nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul:hover > a {
      color: /* your color for mobile */ ;
     background: /* your background for mobile; */ ;
   }`

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you have two main ways of accomplishing this:

1. Loading a different stylesheet if mobile device is detected;
2. If you would like to override pseudo-elements that have already been styled, you can set the same values for hover state as you had for normal state, and override non-mobile styles with `!important` (if needed) through media queries. For example:

### Regular styles:

```
#nav li > a, #nav ul ul > a {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #bbb;
    transition: background 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}
#nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul:hover > a {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .95);
    color: #ccc;
}
```

### Mobile Styles:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #nav li > a, #nav ul ul > a {
        transition: none!important;
    }
    #nav li:hover > a, #nav ul ul:hover > a {
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
        color: #bbb!important;
    }
}
```

Option 1 would be best if you need to make a lot of modifications to the original stylesheet, and option 2 if you only need to adjust a few things.